# Adding a button to an ASP.NET MVC Kendo Scheduler toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-scheduler

I would like to add a button to an ASP.NET MVC Kendo Scheduler toolbar.
I saw this example:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/add-button-to-mvc-scheduler-toolbar

But didn't find a solution.

[I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDjd3.png)

Comment: Tried this example too: http://www.telerik.com/forums/footer-add-additional-button Is there something in `this.view()` for toolbar / header?

Comment: Got it: `function scheduler_dataBound(e) {  var scheduler2 = e.sender,  
            schedulerToolbar = scheduler.element.find(".k-scheduler-toolbar"),  
            datas2 = scheduler.dataSource.data();  
        if (!schedulerToolbar.find(".newMeetingButton").length) {  
            schedulerToolbar.append("<ul class='k-reset'><li class='k-state-default'><a role='button' href='#' class='k-link newMeetingButton' onclick='openEditor()'>Nova reserva</a></li></ul>")  
        }  }`